# Transform SQLite database to SQLCipher database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlcipher, pysqlite, pysqlcipher

My Python program uses the standard Python SQLite database (import sqlite3). All works, I want to cypher the database. I opened it with DB Browser (sqlitebrowser.org) that uses SQLCipher 3/4 and I ciphered it using a key (SQLCipher version 3). Which library must I use to reuse the most part of it?

I understand I need to import the new standard library (SQLCipher) and use code to connect with the database with a key. I don't want to rewrite my code if it's possible. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage encrypted SQLite databases in Python :

1. Download and install free [DB Browser SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and encrypt your database with SQLCipher4 key.
2. Install the Python package to bind with SQLCipher4 database using `pip install sqlcipher3`. If this fails build and intall the package yourself:

   1. [Download SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher).
   2. [Download SQLCipher3](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3).
   3. Copy "sqlite3.c" and "sqlite.h" from SQLCipher folder to SQLCipher3 folder.
   4. [Follow these steps](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3) to build SQLCipher3 package.
   5. Install the package using `pip install path/to/sqlcipher3`.